# Lua regular expression with exactly one match

Tags: regex, lua

can someone help me with lua "regex" aka patterns?

How do I translate this regex into a lua pattern for `string.match()`: `ytplayer\.config\s*=\s*(\{.+?\});`. You can use this site for an explanation what this regex does: https://regex101.com/#pcre

Essentially I want to look for a string which starts with `ytplayer.config =` (note the possible whitespace before and after equal sign), followed by a `{` and until we hit a semicolon.

`ytplayer.config = {a lot of text, special characters and everything else which is possible...}};` this could be a result.

At the moment I have `string.match(s, "ytplayer.config%s=%s({.});")` but it returns an exact copy (checked with kdiff).

Comment: Try `ytplayer%.config%s*=%s*({.-});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look, this will return your captured group:

```
print(string.match("ytplayer.config = {a lot of text, special characters and everything else which is possible...}};", "^ytplayer%.config%s*=%s*({.-});"))
```

Output:

```
{a lot of text, special characters and everything else which is possible...}}
```

The regex is `^ytplayer%.config%s*=%s*({.-});`. In case you do not want check for a string start, remove `^` from the beginning.

Please see [this demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSGRqZHZMVjlOaTA).

In [Lua patterns](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial), `%` escspes "magic symbols". Like `*`, the modifier `-` also matches zero or more occurrences of characters of the original class. However, instead of matching the longest sequence, it matches the shortest one.